# where do i need to deploy my remote event receiver for our sharepoint online; inside external IIS or inside SharePoint app catalog

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365, remote-event-receiver

I am starting a new sharepoint 365 project. and currently i got these sites inside the admin:-

[image]

the next step i did was to create a new app catalog site collection.. Then i created a new sharepoint app inside Visual Studio 2012 professional. but i have these 2 questions:-

1. what should i specify for the below URL field ? the app catalog site collection for my sharepoint online?

[image]

2. now where do i need to deploy the remote event receiver ? inside the app catalog ? or i need to deploy it inside external IIS/Azure ? or i need both ? i know that remote event receivers inside visual studio will contain 2 projects (SP hosted project and Provider hosted project).

Can anyone specify the steps i need to follow, to get my first remote event receivers working for my sharepoint online project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**

You will have to specify your SharePoint Online Developer site URL which will be used to test your add-in.

**Question 2**

When you add a Remote Event Reciever to your Add-in project, it will add a new project that should deploy onto IIS.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the helpful reply. so now when i specify the url for my developer site inside office 365, and i deploy the RER using VS will both projects (the SP & the IIS) inside VS got deployed inside the developer site? second question , now if i want to deploy the RER to my live environment, then do i need to add the .app file inside the app catalog site and to deploy the IIS project inside external IIS (Azure or local IIS)? can you provide more info please?

Comment: Refer this article on how to debug in your test environment http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3a164c/remote-event-receivers-in-sharepoint-2013/. In Production, you have to deploy the .app file to app catalog site and remote web application to the IIS in the on-premises or Azure.

Comment: So the link you provide showed that we can publish the RER to our developer site using visual studio... which is great.. and after testing and verifying it , I need to deploy the remote web application to external IIS, then update the App's elements.xml to reference to the URL points to the webservice's URL. then i need to add the .app to the app catalog site.. is this correct ?

Comment: second question.. now in the link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3a164c/remote-event-receivers-in-sharepoint-2013/ they have added the list which will be firing the RER inside the app project... so not sure if using RER i can attach them to existing lists ? i mean in my case i already have the lists created and they contain data.. but i need to develop RER and attach them to existing lists.. is this a supported scenario ? or the lists need to be part of the App project itself?

Comment: The first question is regarding deployment your assumption is right. Coming to the second question you can not attach the event directly to the list on the host web. But you can attach programmatically using the App Installed event in the remote web. Here is an article that expalins the process https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/

Comment: so generally speaking i can attach the Remote Event Receiver to existing lists and existing sites .. is my assumption correct ?

Comment: Yes. You can do that.

Comment: i had a fast reading about the link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/ but i am not sure if i will be attaching the RER to specified list instances (listA, listB, etc...)? or i can attach them to specific list templates (as i use to do with server-side RER)??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61303/discussion-between-venkat-konjeti-and-john-g).